# RDP to Ubuntu 20.04 via Remmina: "Cannot connect to the "IP" server"

Tags: networking, 20.04, gnome, remote-desktop, xrdp

I'm trying to connect to Ubuntu 20.04 via RDP with Remote Desktop(Windows 10) and Remmina 1.4.29 (Ubuntu) but I haven't managed so far. I can successfully connect with SSH to the server. The firewall is inactive. I have tried all security protocol negotiations (NLA, TLS, RDP, NLA) apart from the default automatic negotiation. Just for the record, I can connect to other Ubuntu 20.04 server via RDP using this version of Remmina.

I also tried to connect after being logged out from the remote desktop but the problem still remains.

Status of xrdp in Ubuntu I'm trying to connect:

```
xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-02-15 17:08:59 EET; 12min ago
       Docs: man:xrdp(8)
             man:xrdp.ini(5)
    Process: 1004 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh /usr/share/xrdp/socksetup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1013 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/xrdp $XRDP_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1020 (xrdp)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18801)
     Memory: 1.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/xrdp.service
             └─1020 /usr/sbin/xrdp

Φεβ 15 17:08:58 iti-1054 xrdp[1013]: (1013)(140503119861568)[INFO ] IPv6 not supported, falling back to IPv4
Φεβ 15 17:08:58 iti-1054 xrdp[1013]: (1013)(140503119861568)[INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
Φεβ 15 17:08:58 iti-1054 xrdp[1013]: (1013)(140503119861568)[DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:3389)
Φεβ 15 17:08:58 iti-1054 systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Can't open PID file /run/xrdp/xrdp.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted
Φεβ 15 17:08:59 iti-1054 systemd[1]: Started xrdp daemon.
Φεβ 15 17:09:00 iti-1054 xrdp[1020]: (1020)(140503119861568)[INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 1020
Φεβ 15 17:09:00 iti-1054 xrdp[1020]: (1020)(140503119861568)[INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
Φεβ 15 17:09:00 iti-1054 xrdp[1020]: (1020)(140503119861568)[INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
Φεβ 15 17:09:00 iti-1054 xrdp[1020]: (1020)(140503119861568)[INFO ] IPv6 not supported, falling back to IPv4
Φεβ 15 17:09:00 iti-1054 xrdp[1020]: (1020)(140503119861568)[INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
```

The error message I get from Remmina when I try to connect is:

```
This window can help you find connection problems.
You can stop and start the logging at any moment using the On/Off switch.
The stats button (Ctrl+T), can be useful to gather system info you may share when reporting a bug.
There is more info about debugging Remmina on https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/wikis/Usage/Remmina-debugging
(DEBUG) - (rcw_map_event) - Mapping: RemminaConnectionWindow
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_map_event) - Calling plugin mapping function
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_open_connection_real) - Opening connection
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_event_init) - Disable smooth scrolling is set to 0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_event_init) - Adding GDK_SMOOTH_SCROLL_MASK
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_open_connection_real) - Have SSH
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - RDP data path is /home/gadolias/.local/share/remmina/RDP
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Not using system proxy settings
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_tunnel_init) - Tunnel init
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - SSH tunnel initialization…
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - Calling remmina_public_get_server_port
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - Calling remmina_public_get_server_port (tunnel)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - server: 160.40.50.88, port: 3389
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_tunnel_init) - protocol_plugin_start_direct_tunnel() returned [160.40.50.88]:3389
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_tunnel_init) - Tunnel has been optionally initialized. Now connecting to 160.40.50.88:3389
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - gfx_h264_available: 1
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Resolution set by the user: 1868x996
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Resolution set after workarounds: 1868x996
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_type: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_username: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_password: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_hostname: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_port: 80
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Network settings not set
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - rdp_keyboard_remapping_list:
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Log level set to to DEBUG
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_disconnect) - Disconnect signal received on RemminaProtocolWidget
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Saving profile
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_store_password) - Password “password” saved for file /home/gadolias/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_iti-1054_160-40-50-88.remmina

(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “ssh_tunnel_password” deleted for file /home/gadolias/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_iti-1054_160-40-50-88.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “gateway_password” deleted for file /home/gadolias/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_iti-1054_160-40-50-88.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “ssh_tunnel_passphrase” deleted for file /home/gadolias/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_iti-1054_160-40-50-88.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Profile saved
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Connection profile states saved
(DEBUG) - (remmina_network_monitor_status) - G_NETWORK_CONNECTIVITY_FULL
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_disconnect) - Could not disconnect
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do your settings look like in remmina? Any boxes ticked on the "advanced" page?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'm using RDP Protocol and network connection type is set to Auto-detect. I also provide the server and the credentials of the account. Concerning the "advanced" tab, Quality is set to Poor, protocol negotiation is set to Automatic negotiation, gateway transport type is set HTTP, TLS is set to Default and all boxes are unticked.